# Simple class in Python error

Tags: python, class, compiler-errors

I get an error message saying something like:

```
TypeError: readFromFile() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
```

This is my very first class in Python btw.

```
from numpy import *
from pycalfem import *
from pycalfem_utils import *

class FlowModel:    
    def __init__(self):
        self.readFromFile()

    def readFromFile(self,filename):
        Inputfile=open(filename,'r')
        ep=readFloat(Inputfile)
        print(str(ep))
        Inputfile.close()


if __name__=="__main__":
    flowmodel=FlowModel()
    flowmodel.readFromFile("indata.txt")
```

Comment: Please review your code formatting, and include the full error traceback.

Comment: Is that indentation accurate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You call `self.readFromFile()` without arguments, when you create the `FlowModel` instance:

```
def __init__(self):
    self.readFromFile()
```

This means that the method is only passed `self`, the first argument, but not the second argument `filename`.

Remove that line; you don't have a filename to pass in there. You already are using that method correctly outside of the `__init__` method after creating the instance.

Comment: Thank you! Im sure I will have more questions to ask as I continue to build this code though :)

Comment: @Sam: do your research each time, and ask new questions if you come across new problems.